# Google Charts draw() method wrong type when given DataTable

Tags: javascript, datatable, google-api, google-visualization

I am attempting to show a line chart with a range filter in Google Charts using HTML and Javascript, but whenever I run the `draw()` function, the code tells me that I used the wrong data datatype for the `draw()` argument (it should be a `DataTable`). However, I contruct my data using `arrayToDataTable()`, which according to the Google Charts API [documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#arraytodatatable), creates a DataTable. Here is my full code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            //Chart data
            google.charts.load('current',{'packages':['controls']});
            google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawDashboard);

            function drawDashboard(){
                var dataSet = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
                    [{label:'date',type:'datetime'},{label:'Bytes from network:Bytes to network',type:'number'}],
                    [new Date(2016,01,23,00,00),1.0],
                    [new Date(2016,01,23,01,00),1.0075187969924813],
                    [new Date(2016,01,23,03,00),1.126865671641791],
                    [new Date(2016,01,24,22,00),0.987012987012987],
                    [new Date(2016,01,25,01,00),1.0],
                    [new Date(2016,01,25,02,00),0.9166666666666666],
                    [new Date(2016,01,25,10,00),1.0],
                    [new Date(2016,01,26,12,00),1.0],
                    [new Date(2016,01,27,17,00),0.9864864864864865],
                    [new Date(2016,01,28,22,00),0.03125],
                    [new Date(2016,02,01,22,00),0.97],
                ]);

                var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

                var dateRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({'controlType':'ChartRangeFilter','containerId':'filter_div','options': {'filterColumnLabel':'date'}});

                var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({'chartType':'LineChart','containerId':'curve_chart','options':{'title': 'Total Bytes from the Source Network to Total Bytes To the Source Network per Day','curveType': 'function','legend': {'postition':'bottom'}}});

                dashboard.bind(dateRangeFilter,lineChart);

                dashboard.draw(dataSet);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--draw charts using corresponding div tags-->
        <div id="dashboard_div">
            <div id="filter_div"></div>
            <div id="curve_chart" style="width:900px;height:500px"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As one can see, I create a variable called `dataSet` using `google.visualization.arrayToDataTable()`, which returns a `DataTable`. Then, at the bottom of the `drawDashboard()` method, I call `dashboard.draw(dataSet)`, which throws the error

```
You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView
```

I'm not sure why it is throwing this error, since `dataSet` is clearly an instance of the `DataTable` class. I tried clearing my cache and cookies multiple times, but to no avail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing the reference to `http://www.google.com/jsapi`

You should only need `loader.js`

I've also found when using `loader.js`, packages need to be included, in addition to `'controls'`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['controls', 'corechart'],
    callback: drawDashboard
});

function drawDashboard() {
    var dataSet = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        [{label:'date',type:'datetime'},{label:'Bytes from network:Bytes to network',type:'number'}],
        [new Date(2016,01,23,00,00),1.0],
        [new Date(2016,01,23,01,00),1.0075187969924813],
        [new Date(2016,01,23,03,00),1.126865671641791],
        [new Date(2016,01,24,22,00),0.987012987012987],
        [new Date(2016,01,25,01,00),1.0],
        [new Date(2016,01,25,02,00),0.9166666666666666],
        [new Date(2016,01,25,10,00),1.0],
        [new Date(2016,01,26,12,00),1.0],
        [new Date(2016,01,27,17,00),0.9864864864864865],
        [new Date(2016,01,28,22,00),0.03125],
        [new Date(2016,02,01,22,00),0.97],
    ]);

    var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

    var dateRangeFilter = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({'controlType':'ChartRangeFilter','containerId':'filter_div','options': {'filterColumnLabel':'date'}});

    var lineChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({'chartType':'LineChart','containerId':'curve_chart','options':{'title': 'Total Bytes from the Source Network to Total Bytes To the Source Network per Day','curveType': 'function','legend': {'postition':'bottom'}}});

    dashboard.bind(dateRangeFilter,lineChart);

    dashboard.draw(dataSet);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
    <div id="filter_div"></div>
    <div id="curve_chart" style="width:900px;height:500px"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: According to google chart's example page (and most other pages I looked at), you only need to import the `controls` package. Is this a new change to also require the `corechart` package? When you only include the `controls`, you get an error saying that `google.load is not a function`.

Comment: I've found when using `jsapi` _alone_, only `'controls'` is needed, but not the case with `loader.js`

Comment: apparently, a buggy version was released recently --> [We have pushed Google Charts v44](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/tdswEASPEKA) -- [Google Visualization Charts API examples are broken](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35648530/5090771)

Comment: Removing "jsapi" considerably improved the reliability of Google charts for me.