# Google Visualization Charts API examples are broken, how to fix them?

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

See this page, for example: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start

Depending on a browser we see one of errors as follows:

- `Uncaught ReferenceError: Hh is not defined` (in Chrome)
- `TypeError: chart.draw is not a function` (in Firefox)

JSFiddle examples linked from the documentation and attempts to work with charts manually fail with the same diagnostics.

Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/tdswEASPEKA Seems to be a recent breakage.

Comment: See also: https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2182

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Seems to be [a bad release](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/tdswEASPEKA) (v44). Until it is fixed, the workaround is to explicitly specify previous version of the API to load instead of using current:

```
-     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['gantt']});
+     google.charts.load('43', {'packages':['gantt']});
```

Please note that this will indeed freeze your charts version and you will not get new features and bugfixes unless you will revert the changes.

Comment: I get almost daily complete breakdowns of google charts. Every time there's a new release, the google.load function breaks.  Specifying a version number as in the example provided seems to have stopped the madness. Thanks.