# Google Charts, sometimes it works and sometimes it does not?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

Google Charts works sometimes and sometimes it does not work! Please notice that I am using the same data in both cases ,no difference at all, when it does not work it throws a message error in the console.

I am sure that the problem is not happening from my side, it is happening from google side. Did this problem happen to anyone before and does it happen often?

Comment: @WhiteHat Yes it is the same answer but for different question, he did not mention that sometimes it works and sometimes it does not work using the same data in both cases, this part is very important in the question, Please let me know if I should click on "That solved my problem!" or I do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many duplicate reports on this issue.  There seems to have been a bit of a problem with the loader system with caching browsers and caching proxies keeping redirects from the 'current' version during the latest release.

Switching to a fixed version (43 for before this update, or 44 for the new version) has been an effective workaround for most people.

This the Google Visualization team assures us this is a temporary issue, will solve itself as caches expire, and they'll look into solving the underlying problem before the next release.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to explicitly specify previous version of the API to load instead of using current:

```
-     google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
+     google.charts.load('43', {'packages':['bar']});
```

Here is a [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-visualization-api/tdswEASPEKA) to a discussion about the new version v44 from Google Charts team.

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35648674/1857295