# Handling events for markers in a geochart chartwrapper

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Can anyone help me to create an event listener for a geochart chartwrapper with markers ? My objective is to throw an alert when the user clicks on a marker.

I have tried

```
  google.visualization.events.addListener(pn_1,'ready', function(){
     console.log('dashboard is ready');     
     google.visualization.events.addListener(pn_1_ch,'select',function(){    
        alert('Some random alert');
     });    
  });
```

But so far it doesn't work. It throws no error or whatsoever. However I do get the 'dashboard is ready' message. It's only the second eventlistener that isn't working.

Any clues ? Thanks a lot :)

BTW pn_1 refers to the dashboard and pn_1_ch refers the the chartwrapper object :)

Comment: take a look at the example [here](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapper-class) -- you have to wait for the 'ready' event on the chartwrapper, then assign events to the chart itself -- `wrapper.getChart()`

Comment: I tried that, but it still doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing all the code, there are several things to check...

First, [GeoCharts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart) require both loaders. (`/loader.js` and `/jsapi`)

Next, I'm using frozen version `44` due to recent [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35648674/5090771).

As for handling events, listen for the `'ready'` event on the [ChartWrapper](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#chartwrapperobject).
Once fired, you can access the GeoChart via `.getChart()` in order to listen for the `'select'` event.

With [Dashboards](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#dashboard), the `'ready'` event is fired anytime the chart is re-drawn.
Here, I remove the event from the ChartWrapper to avoid adding duplicate `'select'` listeners when the [NumberRangeFilter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#numberrangefilter) is applied...

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawDashboard,
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart', 'geochart']
});

function drawDashboard() {
  var msgDiv = document.getElementById('message_div');

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['City',   'Population', 'Area'],
    ['Rome',      2761477,    1285.31],
    ['Milan',     1324110,    181.76],
    ['Naples',    959574,     117.27],
    ['Turin',     907563,     130.17],
    ['Palermo',   655875,     158.9],
    ['Genoa',     607906,     243.60],
    ['Bologna',   380181,     140.7],
    ['Florence',  371282,     102.41],
    ['Fiumicino', 67370,      213.44],
    ['Anzio',     52192,      43.43],
    ['Ciampino',  38262,      11]
  ]);

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
      document.getElementById('dashboard_div'));

  var rangeSlider = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'NumberRangeFilter',
    containerId: 'filter_div',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'Area'
    }
  });

  var geoChart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'GeoChart',
    containerId: 'chart_div',
    options: {
      region: 'IT',
      displayMode: 'markers',
      colorAxis: {colors: ['green', 'blue']}
    }
  });

  // listen for 'ready' event on ChartWrapper
  google.visualization.events.addListener(geoChart, 'ready', function () {
    // remove 'ready' listener to avoid adding multiple 'select' events
    google.visualization.events.removeAllListeners(geoChart);
    msgDiv.innerHTML += 'ChartWrapper Ready<br/>';

    // listen for 'select' event on GeoChart
    google.visualization.events.addListener(geoChart.getChart(), 'select', function () {
      msgDiv.innerHTML += 'GeoChart Selected - ' +
        JSON.stringify(geoChart.getChart().getSelection()) + '<br/>';
    });
  });

  dashboard.bind(rangeSlider, geoChart);
  dashboard.draw(data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<div id="dashboard_div">
  <div id="filter_div"></div>
  <div id="chart_div"></div>
  <div id="message_div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I managed to fix my code yesterday. As it turns out, a geochart and a geomap (deprecated) aren't the same thing at all, even if google tends to make us think both terms are interchangeable. (lol blame the ***** documentation.) On a GEOMAP, you can't set event-listeners on markers, believe me, I've tried ^^. On the other hand, you did point out something interesting as I realized the 'ready' event on dashboard was being fired multiple times ^^, you could add a one-time listener though, would work as well. Anyway, thanks a lot man :)

Comment: cheers, glad you were able to resolve the issue. `addOneTimeListener` would make sense here...