# Average line for current data in a Google ComboChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Hi guys am currently using a combo chart, and am trying to get an average of all values and show a line on the chart to represent the average for each agent.

I have done some digging and there was one resource that I did try to use but it was throwing up errors and I have struggled to find a solution for this.

Below is a JSFiddle example of how my chart looks but I need an average line for all the values for each agent and displayed an average line across for each agent.

[JSFiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/og2aujff/1/)

And below is the JS code for the JS Fiddle:

```
jQuery(function($) {
  google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: drawChartAverage,
    packages: ['corechart']
  });

  function drawChartAverage() {
    var result = [
      ['Agents', 'Minutes'],
      ['1', 44],
      ['2', 22],
      ['3', 11],
      ['4', 34]];
    var options = {
      title: 'Average Minutes cross Agents',
      vAxis: {
        title: 'Minutes'
      },
      hAxis: {
        title: 'Agent'
      },
      seriesType: 'bars',
      series: {
        1: {
          type: 'line'
        }
      }
    };
    var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);
    var chartAvg = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chartAvg'));
    chartAvg.draw(chartdata, options);
  }
})
```

I need it to look something like the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/CbD3T/5/) I have attempted to use but no joy in doing so.

But at gives you an idea of what am trying to do!

Comment: first, I would recommend trying [frozen version 43 or 44](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35648674/5090771), due to recent problems...

Comment: @WhiteHat Ah hello again, ill look into this I have had a few issues but I dont think it has much to with what am trying to do.

Comment: i'm not able to access the first fiddle (jshell) -- it's blocked here at work. does the code match the above?

Comment: @WhiteHat Yes it is I stuck in there because of the reason you stated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the examples provided...

```js
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawChartAverage,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChartAverage() {
  var result = [
    ['Agents', 'Minutes'],
    ['1', 44],
    ['2', 22],
    ['3', 11],
    ['4', 34]
  ];
  var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);

  // Create a DataView that adds another column which is all the same (empty-string) to be able to aggregate on.
  var viewWithKey = new google.visualization.DataView(chartdata);
  viewWithKey.setColumns([0, 1, {
      type: 'string',
      label: '',
      calc: function (d, r) {
          return ''
      }
  }])

  // Aggregate the previous view to calculate the average. This table should be a single table that looks like:
  // [['', AVERAGE]], so you can get the Average with .getValue(0,1)
  var group = google.visualization.data.group(viewWithKey, [2], [{
      column: 1,
      id: 'avg',
      label: 'average',
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.avg,
      'type': 'number'
  }]);

  // Create a DataView where the third column is the average.
  var dv = new google.visualization.DataView(chartdata);
  dv.setColumns([0, 1, {
      type: 'number',
      label: 'average',
      calc: function (dt, row) {
          // round average up / down
          return Math.round(group.getValue(0, 1));
      }
  }]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Average Minutes cross Agents',
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Minutes'
    },
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Agent'
    },
    seriesType: 'bars',
    series: {
      1: {
        type: 'line'
      }
    }
  };

  var chartAvg = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chartAvg'));
  chartAvg.draw(dv, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chartAvg"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, that exactly what am looking for, only thing would be rounding that average value up or down somehow if you have any suggestions for that, I had used this example previously but I had not had this before all the aforementioned logic `var chartdata = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(result);`

Comment: I got it in the end just you posted this haha! +1 for it anyway!