# Google Charts Javascript, using two arrays for data input for a line chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to create a line chart using the Google Charts package. The problem I have is that I want to plot data from two Javascript arrays. I did find some code showing how to do this for a barchart, but I can not get the same code to work for creating a line chart. This is the code I have so far.

```
<html>
<head>


  <!--Load the AJAX API-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"> </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


    var time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
    var suseptible = [0, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 9, 9, 9];

    function drawChart(){

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'Time');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Suseptible');

        for(var i=0; i < time.length; i++){
            var row = [time[i], suseptible[i]];
            data.addRow(row);
        }



        var options = {

        };

        var chart = new  google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_id'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }


</script>
</head>

<body>
<!--Div that will hold the pie chart-->
<div id="chart_id"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone explain the basics for how to do this. I have been looking in the Google Charts documentation, but I am having a hard time solving this.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would recommend using `loader.js` instead of `jsapi` to load the library.
Loading frozen version `'44'` due to [recent issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35648674/5090771).

Next, I noticed you are using [`arrayToDataTable`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#arraytodatatable)
This requires an array argument be passed (see examples from link).
Use this when your data is already complete and exists in an array.

Next you need a domain column, typically the first column is a date or label for which the value represents. In this example, I use the array index as the "Id".

```js
// load frozen version 44
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

// init array data
var time = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];
var suseptible = [0, 4, 5, 2, 6, 7, 3, 9, 9, 9];

function drawChart(){
  // create DataTable
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'Id');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Time');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Suseptible');

  // load data
  for (var i = 0; i < time.length; i++) {
    var row = [i, time[i], suseptible[i]];
    data.addRow(row);
  }

  var options = {};

  var chart = new  google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_id'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_id"></div>
```