# Google Chart Geomap not working

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-visualization

I tried to use Google Chart Geomap on my Squarespace site. But i'm getting blank container there.

Here is source url: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geomap?csw=1#regionsexample

Please note, that even this page with examples of usage shows blank containers. Same with JSFiddle placed on that page. I edited JsFiddle by placing my ApiKey, but I'm still getting the same result.

Then I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648530/google-visualization-charts-api-examples-are-broken-how-to-fix-them) and played with number of versions. But it didn't help. I tried 45, 44, 43 and 42.

How to make it work?

My links to Squarespace page is (if necessary): https://campisano.squarespace.com/map-1

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geomap'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

      function drawMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};
        options['dataMode'] = 'regions';

        var container = document.getElementById('regions_div');
        var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoMap(container);

        geomap.draw(data, options);
      };
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

:
My [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsovzdhv/).

Comment: for starters, the package should be `'geochart'`, not `'geomap'`...

Answer (score 0):

for starters, the package should be `'geochart'`, not `'geomap'`

along with the chart object...

```
google.visualization.GeoChart
```

not...

```
google.visualization.GeoMap
```

finally, there is not an option for --> `dataMode`

it should be --> `displayMode`

see following working snippet...

```js
      google.charts.load('current', {
        'packages':['geochart'],
        // Note: you will need to get a mapsApiKey for your project.
        // See: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_load_libs#load-settings
        'mapsApiKey': 'AIzaSyD-9tSrke72PouQMnMX-a7eZSW0jkFMBWY'
      });
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

      function drawMap() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['Country', 'Popularity'],
          ['Germany', 200],
          ['United States', 300],
          ['Brazil', 400],
          ['Canada', 500],
          ['France', 600],
          ['RU', 700]
        ]);

        var options = {};
        options['displayMode'] = 'regions';

        var container = document.getElementById('regions_div');
        var geomap = new google.visualization.GeoChart(container);

        geomap.draw(data, options);
      };
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="regions_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```