# Conflict between Google Analytics Embed API and Google Charts

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-visualization, google-analytics-api

There seems to be a conflict when I load Google Analytics Embed API and Google Charts on the same page, more specifically when I use Embed API to draw charts, too.

To make it more interesting, the problem only occurs when the charts are of different type, e.g. Embed API: TABLE and Charts: LINE

Embed API chart is loaded first and works as expected.
Charts LINE chart is loaded second and returns this error:

> You called the draw() method with the wrong type of data rather than a DataTable or DataView

I have a feeling that Embed API charts override this function:

```
google.charts.load('current', {
    packages: ['corechart', 'line', 'table']
});
```

---

UPDATE

Answer for this question: [Google Charts draw() method wrong type when given DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636075/google-charts-draw-method-wrong-type-when-given-datatable) suggests removing the reference to `http://www.google.com/jsapi`, but then Google Embed API charts stop working because `window.google.load` is no longer defined, instead there is `window.google.charts.load` which is needed for Google Charts but seems not to work work Embed API charts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Charts draw() method wrong type when given DataTable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636075/google-charts-draw-method-wrong-type-when-given-datatable)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and fixed the script loading conflicts.
The solution is to only include the newer chart loader.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

Then, before loading the google charts api, run the extra code [suggested by Daniel LaLiberte](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-visualization-api/RQXKcb7pOvk/go2VzIefBQAJ;context-place=forum/google-visualization-api):

```
//Handles differences in load functions
google.load = google.load || google.charts.load;
google.setOnLoadCallback = google.setOnLoadCallback || google.charts.setOnLoadCallback;

//Loads the google analytics API
(function (w, d, s, g, js, fs) {
            //if ($('#googleCache').length > 0) return;
            g = w.gapi || (w.gapi = {});
            g.analytics = {
                q: [],
                ready: function (f) {
                    this.q.push(f);
                }
            };
            js = d.createElement(s);
            fs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            js.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
            js.id = "googleCache";
            fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fs);
            js.onload = function () {
                g.load('analytics');
            };
}(window, document, 'script'));

//Load the charts you want
google.charts.load('current', { packages: ['corechart', 'table', 'line', 'geochart'] });
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't fix the issue for me.