# Using the Charts API to create a scatter chart in Google AppMaker

Tags: google-apps-script, google-app-maker

Appmaker has builtins for Line and Bar charts, but not for Scatter charts.

It appears that I can access [Charts.newScatterChart()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/charts/charts#newScatterChart()) from within AppMaker scripts (it shows up in the autocomplete when I try to use it in a script). However, I don't see how to display those charts in the UI.

How do I use the Charts API to create a scatter chart and display it in my AppMaker UI?

Comment: A scatter chart builder should return a `Chart` just like a line chart builder or a bar chart builder.

Comment: thank you. and then what do I do with that Chart object? How do I attach it to the UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, App Maker will not help you a lot with charts that it doesn't support out of the box. So, we will need to go through excited journey.

1. First things first we need to figure out concurrency. We need to have chart script on the client before we receive data to render to avoid numerous reperetive checks and inline initializations. In order to do that we need to add visualization library of choice as external JavaScript resource and handle its load. In this answer I'll use [Google's Material Scatter Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/scatterchart#creating-material-scatter-charts) for reference. Here is a link to its loader library `https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js`

```javascript
// onAppStart event handler
loader.suspendLoad();

google.charts
      .load('current', { 'packages': ['scatter'] })
      .then(function(){
         loader.resumeLoad();
      });
```

The result of the first step will look like this
[image: Initialize chart]

2. Prepare your data model. It can be either [Calculated](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/calculated) or [real one](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/models/cloudsql). The model should contain at least to numeric fields (one for x-axis and one for y-axis).
3. Add container for the chart in can be HTML or Panel widget.
4. Bind your widget container to the model's datasource
5. Map datasource's items to chart's [DataTable](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable)

```javascript
// chart container's onDataLoad event handler
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('number', 'X');
data.addColumn('number', 'Y1');
data.addColumn('number', 'Y2');

var rows = [];

widget.datasource.items.forEach(function(item) {
  rows.push([item.X, item.Y1, item.Y2]);
});

data.addRows(rows);

var chart = new google.charts.Scatter(widget.getElement());

// If you are using built-in App Maker charts you can
// encounter this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35636075
chart.draw(data);
```